# setState doesn't get updated the first time in react

Tags: reactjs

I have two components and I want to set new value to state from child component when button is clicked, so I have the following

```
// parent component 

const [clickedSubmit, setClickedSubmit] = useState(false);
const [state, setState] = useState({
   ..,
   val: '',
})

  function handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setClickedSubmit(true);

    console.log(state);
  }

// child component 

..
useEffect(() => {
  if (clickedSubmit) {
   setState({
        ...state,
        val: sigRef.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL("image/png"),
      });
     }
}, [clickedSubmit])
```

`state.val` is empty when I first click the button and only show value after first time, when I console.log outside of `handleOnSubmit` function, it logs two time which first time is empty and second has value. Why is that happening and how can I only get the state which has updated value inside `handleOnSubmit` function ?

Comment: I feel like there is a typo on this line: `const [state, setState] = useState({ .., val: '' })`
What is the value you are trying to initialise here?

Comment: Empty string as initialised value for `val`, when user click submit btn, I am trying to change value of `val` by calling `setState` from child component by changing `clickedSubmit` to `true` but state is not updating immediately in `handleOnSubmit` function.

Answer (score 1):

Because the change of state is asynchronous
Therefore you will not be able to check the state of the state immediately

You can follow it with the `useEffect` function

like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("useEffect state",state)
},[staet])
```

Comment: Yes, I see value in `useEffect` function, but I can't find a way to get only the updated value using `useEffect` and pass to handleOnSubmit function. Now, I made another button to save that value and then another button to save the final values and it works.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw 